# How to remove outliers to make a better curve fitting in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a curve using data I obtain from an image. The problem is that sometimes the image has more points than the ones corresponding to the curve so the fitting is not correct.

For example this image where the data on the right made the prediction deviate from the curve.

[image: Plot]

Is there a way to detect this kind of outliers and make a better fitting?

The code I'm using is:

```
#CURVE
trend = np.polyfit(x_list,y_list,2)
trendpoly = np.poly1d(trend) 

new_x = np.linspace(min(x_list), max(x_list))
new_y = trendpoly(new_x)
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, 'o', new_x, new_y,'*')
```

Edit: To give more details, the image I'm processing is being captured by camera and process to obtain a line. The ideal scenario is to obtain a curve, as shown in the second image. Therefore I'm attempting a curve fitting, as seen in the third image.

[ideal scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QQ1R.png)

[the expected fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRlG3.png)

The problem occurs when the image captured is deviated and there are points that ruin the fitting. As I don't know how will be the figure I can't establish a number for a higher polinomial regression

Comment: Hi Javier. First off, it seems like the curve you're fitting is not going to fare much better by just removing outliers. You should try fitting higher order polynomials in addition to a polynomial with 2 terms. Regarding outlier removal, take a look at RANSAC (RANdom SAmple Consensus), which is an algorithm that attempts to regress a curve that is robust to outliers. You can read more here: https://hands-on.cloud/using-the-random-sample-consensus-ransac-algorithm-in-python/#h-applying-the-ransac-algorithm-to-the-regression-dataset

Comment: fitting is not just a magic thing that will give you a perfect description of your data if you remove a few outliers, it is highly dependent on what the actual data describes and what assumption(s) you make about it in your fitting. You must give complete details.

Comment: At the very least, show what you expect a good fit to look like.

Comment: I added more details, thanks for the comments